# How to make an addition with types byte and short

Tags: c#, addition, operator-keyword

I saw in previous questions that it is impossible to make a direct addition without a cast but...
How do you explain that this following tip works?

```
byte startValue = 2;
byte addingValue1 = 7;
byte addingValue2 = 8;

startValue += addingValue1;
startValue += addingValue2;

Console.writeLine("The value of startValue was 2 but now is " + starValue);
// startValue = 17
```

In the same way, it is possible to use operator ++ in loops like for():

```
byte limit = 20;
for(byte i=0; i < limit; i++)
{
 Console.WriteLine("Value i =" + i);
}
```

So... why the simple addition between two byte/short variables does not work but these two operators += and ++ work ?

Regards,
Zoh

I tried to read how these operators work compared to operator +.

Comment: Where is the short variable ?

Comment: "I saw in previous questions that it is impossible to make a direct addition without a cast" That is not true at all. You can totally do "someByte + someShort". It's just that the type of the result becomes `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The compound operators are a special case, see [the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12214-compound-assignment).

> An operation of the form `x «op»= y` is processed by applying binary operator overload resolution (§12.4.5) as if the operation was written `x «op» y`. Then,
>
> - If the return type of the selected operator is implicitly convertible to the type of x, the operation is evaluated as `x = x «op» y`, except that x is evaluated only once.
> - Otherwise, if the selected operator is a predefined operator, if the return type of the selected operator is explicitly convertible to the type of x , and if y is implicitly convertible to the type of x  or the operator is a shift operator, then the operation is evaluated as `x = (T)(x «op» y)`, where T is the type of x, except that x is evaluated only once.
>
> ...
>
> The second rule above permits `x «op»= y` to be evaluated as `x = (T)(x «op» y)` in certain contexts. The rule exists such that the predefined operators can be used as compound operators when the left operand is of type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, or char. Even when both arguments are of one of those types, the predefined operators produce a result of type int, as described in §12.4.7.3. Thus, without a cast it would not be possible to assign the result to the left operand.

As you can see, there is an explicit rule which casts the result back to `byte` / `short`, precisely so that you can do `byteValue += intValue` without needing to add a cast yourself.

Similarly for the [postfix increment/decrement operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12815-postfix-increment-and-decrement-operators):

> The run-time processing of a postfix increment or decrement operation of the form x++ or x-- consists of the following steps:
>
> - If x is classified as a variable:
>
>   - x is evaluated to produce the variable.
>   - The value of x is saved.
>   - The saved value of x is converted to the operand type of the selected operator and the operator is invoked with this value as its argument.
>   - **The value returned by the operator is converted to the type of X and stored in the location given by the earlier evaluation of x.**
>   - The saved value of x becomes the result of the operation.